# Как работает jQuery.noConflict()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

В [исходном коде](https://gist.github.com/w3lifer/054780c14ca94b28ded21c08ae97f4d3#file-jquery-3-0-0-js-L10008) (**осторожно**: 10000 строк) у нас следующее:

```
var

    // Map over jQuery in case of overwrite
    _jQuery = window.jQuery,

    // Map over the $ in case of overwrite
    _$ = window.$;

jQuery.noConflict = function( deep ) {
    if ( window.$ === jQuery ) {
        window.$ = _$;
    }

    if ( deep && window.jQuery === jQuery ) {
        window.jQuery = _jQuery;
    }

    return jQuery;
};
```

Непонятно зачем мы вводим `_$` и `_jQuery` ...

<s>Пока готовил вопрос понял как это работает; представляю ответ ниже.</s>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Представим, что у нас помимо `jQuery` есть ещё библиотека `XXX`, которая тоже использует переменную `window.$` как основной идентификатор.

1. Мы загружаем библиотеку `XXX` — определяется переменная `window.$`.
2. Мы хотим использовать её (переменную `window.$`) для доступа к библиотеке `XXX`; но в тоже время *после* загрузки библиотеки `XXX` мы подгружаем `jQuery`, которая [переопределит](https://gist.github.com/w3lifer/054780c14ca94b28ded21c08ae97f4d3#file-jquery-3-0-0-js-L10031) `window.$` под себя; НО сначала (перед переопределением) `jQuery` сделает бэкап значения переменной `window.$` в свою локальную переменную `_$`:

   ```
   var

       // Map over jQuery in case of overwrite
       _jQuery = window.jQuery, // На это пока не обращаем внимание.

       // Map over the $ in case of overwrite
       _$ = window.$; // Вот здесь.
   ```

То есть после загрузки `jQuery` в переменной `window.$` будет `jQuery`, а в *локальной переменной* `_$` *функции* `jQuery` будет проживать библиотека `XXX`.

Именно поэтому в [документации](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/) и говорится, что метод `jQuery.noConflict()` (если мы хотим исключить конфликты) нужно вызвать сразу после загрузки библиотеки и перед её использованием:

> In order to avoid these conflicts, you need to put jQuery in no-conflict mode **immediately after it is loaded** onto the page and **before you attempt to use** jQuery in your page.

То есть когда мы вызовем метод `jQuery.noConflict()`, произойдёт следующее:

```
jQuery.noConflict = function( deep ) {
    // Здесь будет `true`, так как у нас в `window.$` на данный момент
    // находится `jQuery`.
    if ( window.$ === jQuery ) {
        // Так как мы хотим исключить конфликты, то мы устанавливаем
        // в качестве значения переменной `window.$` сделанный ранее бэкап,
        // то есть возвращем исходное значение этой переменной до
        // загрузки `jQuery`.
        window.$ = _$; // Теперь в `window.$` опять живёт библиотека `XXX`.
    }

    if ( deep && window.jQuery === jQuery ) {
        window.jQuery = _jQuery;
    }

    return jQuery;
};
```

С `_jQuery` по аналогии ...

---

<s>Принимаются правки и подзатыльники, так как я только начал изучать `jQuery` и могу ошибаться.</s>

Comment: Хоть и знаю как оно работает, с удовольствием прочитал, вот бы все функции так разобрать!